# Google Actions Implementation

Tags: gmail, action, google-developer-tools

I am currently running an ecommerce store. I want to use google actions & reviews in my emails so I can get reviews and offer one click actions from there. I am pretty novice, and have found this very useful. Can any body please help with how to get started? What are the requirements? Are there any email related requirements as SPF, DKIM , DMARC etc?

I would be very thankful for this support

Answer (score 0):

I recently had similar questions myself because we wanted to provide shipment tracking information integrated in Google Now and [jotted down the process](https://joakimhedlund.com/blog/implementing-quick-action-buttons-for-gmail) I had to go through.

Since you want to offer the ability to post reviews your process will be a little different (as is described here: [Review Action Email Markup - Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/review-action)) and needs a backend to handle HTTP POST requests.

Saxed from my blog about my journey to get tracking actions up and running:

> 1. Implement the Microdata schema in our email templates according to the Google Developer examples for the [Parcel Delivery
>      action](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/parcel-delivery).
>      We went with the basic option to keep things simple. (See end results
>      further down this page)
> 2. [Validate the data](https://www.google.com/webmasters/markup-tester/). Fail
>      validation.
> 3. Realize that the format in the examples was invalid (according to Google's own validator)
> 4. Tweak the tags and add one or two missing ones.
> 5. Validate again. Pass.
> 6. Verify that we have DKIM keys set up for the sender domain(s).
> 7. Send an email from our customer service email address to the same address to verify the button works (it wont work for other recipients
>      until Gmail whitelists you)
> 8. Send another email, to Google this time. This is part of the registration process.
> 9. [Fill in the registration form](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/registering-with-google)
>      so that Google's people can validate your schema.
> 10. Receive reply from Google that they've forwarded my email to the right people.
> 11. ???
> 12. It took 3 working days (Wednesday to Monday) and then I got an email from Google saying we were live.

We use Mandrill and their template feature. The template ended up with this metadata in the bottom, leaving the rest of the markup untouched:

```
<body>

{{-- lots of tables for layout --}}

<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ParcelDelivery">
  <div itemprop="deliveryAddress" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
    <meta itemprop="streetAddress" content="{{ deliveryAddressStreet }}"/>
    <meta itemprop="addressLocality" content="{{ deliveryAddressCity }}"/>
    <meta itemprop="addressRegion" content="{{ deliveryAddressCountry }}"/>
    <meta itemprop="addressCountry" content="{{ deliveryAddressCountry }}"/>
    <meta itemprop="postalCode" content="{{ deliveryAddressZip }}"/>
  </div>
  <meta itemprop="expectedArrivalUntil" content="{{ expectedDelivery }}"/>
  <div itemprop="carrier" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
      <meta itemprop="name" content="{{ carrier }}"/>
  </div>
  {{#each products}}
  <div itemprop="itemShipped" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
    <meta itemprop="name" content="{{ description }}"/>
  </div>
  {{/each}}
  <div itemprop="partOfOrder" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Order">
    <meta itemprop="orderNumber" content="{{ ordernumber }}"/>
    <div itemprop="merchant" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
      <meta itemprop="name" content="Our Store Name"/>
    </div>
    <link itemprop="orderStatus" href="http://schema.org/OrderInTransit"/>
  </div>
  <meta itemprop="trackingNumber" content="{{ shipmentTrackingNo }}"/>
  <link itemprop="trackingUrl" href="{{ shipmentTrackingLink }}"/>
  <div itemprop="potentialAction" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/TrackAction">
    <link itemprop="target" href="{{ shipmentTrackingLink }}"/>
    <link itemprop="url" href="{{ shipmentTrackingLink }}"/>
    <meta itemprop="name" content="Track shipment"/>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```